# Objective C Mime Parser for IMAP response

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, mime

I want to Parse a NSDATA which contains IMAP response, For ex

```
Date: Tue, 18 Sep 2012 02:50:54 +0000 (GMT)
From: xx@xx.com
To: yy@yy.com
Message-ID: 7034025
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_16_9157073.1347936657899"
Message-Source: IMAP

------=_Part_16_9157073.1347936657899
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: text.txt
Content-Location: text.txt
X-Section-ID: Text-Section

Test Message
------=_Part_16_9157073.1347936657899
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: attachment_1
Content-Location: image_1347936646.jpg
X-Section-ID: Thumbnail-Section

ˇÿˇ‡ ...........

------=_Part_16_9157073.1347936657899--
```

From this I want to extract both Parts(Text & Image). Can anybody suggest me an Objective-c mime parser.

Note: The image part is in Binary not encoded with base64.

Comment: Might I recommend the [MailCore](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore) or [EtPanKit](https://github.com/CodaFi/etPanKit) frameworks if you are doing anything email related?

Comment: MailCore internally uses LibetPan,it doesn't parser for binary data, But When the attachment is encoded with Base64 it does. I'm using the mailcore only.